Any 2FA (TOTP) app that syncs between iPhone and Ubuntu?
Does anyone know of a 2FA (TOTP) service or setup that syncs your 2FA codes/accounts between an iPhone app and a Linux or web app that you can use from Ubuntu desktop?
I used to use Authy to do exactly this but they deprecated their desktop app.
Most 2FA apps seem to be mobile only.
I believe Bitwarden Authenticator would work but that's not the most secure solution for me: I already use Bitwarden as my password manager, and it's more secure to use a separate service for 2FA rather than storing your passwords and your 2FA codes in the same place.
I believe 1Password would also work but you have to pay for an account.
Any others?

Is a physical device like a YubiKey an option?
